# RoundCube not displaying mails with attachments over certain size

Tags: php, iis, roundcube

The setup is fairly simple, it's Windows Server 2019, with hMailServer as a mailserver, and IIS hosting RoundCube, and of course, PHP.

Sending mails work fine, but when the attachment gets over like 30-50 MB, they get sent, but it isn't displayed in the body.

Here's what I've done to increase the size

- Increased Size in SMTP of hMail
- Increased MaxContentLength in Request Filtering of IIS
- Increased max_post/max_upload (Not the actual variables) in php.ini
- Increased size in RoundCube config

I have disabled all the plugins in RoundCube since the mails wouldn't even be sent with the plugins

Is there a certain plugin to resolve this or does RoundCube have limitations in attachments other than the IIS' limit?

Being able to send about 500MB max would be the best for me.

Comment: Does the vendor offer Squirrel Mail as well. I can choose either. Squirrel Mail may possibly help you.